# What options are there for transferring one particular webapp user's data onto another DB instance without suffering PK collision?

Tags: sql-server, database, web-applications, architecture, uniqueidentifier

**EDITED**

When we first architected our web app years ago, we chose auto-increment int for all of our users' data.  However, we are now getting burned by how hard it is to transfer specific user's data (multiple tables with one-to-many relationships) to another non-empty database instance (with the same table strictures).

While `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON | OFF` may work for some tables, with our current architecture we will still run into problem because certain 'many' in a 'one-to-many' relation may collide with the destination DB.

Inspired by Pam Lahoud's answer below, I started researching on non-clustered PK and PK alternatives.  Then I come across [Selecting an Appropriate Primary Key for a Distributed Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011) from MSDN, and "Keys That Include a Node Identifier" caught my eye.  Anyone has experience with this kind of architecture?

Comment: I don't really see how you are burned. Explain your difficulties please. Almost every modern DB / ORM support autoincrement keys and that should be no problem.

Comment: @FractalizeR with guid as pk, we could have just insert the record over to the new db as is without re-setting pk/fk for relational data.  With auto-increment ints, we most likely would have to insert them then set the fk appropriately?

Comment: I wish you would have clarified what PK and FK stand for first. OK so PK is Primary key?  FK is Foreign key?  I used to transfer data in ASCII format first.  Can't give you an elaborate answer to why it seemed to have worked more on a universal level for me in the past, but the data ended transferring more effortlessly and complete.  I am assuming that it depends on the type of data you wish to transfer. I hope my response can be some lead to your project completion.  I do not see a problem with transferring pk/fk either.  You keep the tables separate anyway.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. If you want to transfer your database to another instance of SQL Server with the same or later version, just do a standard backup, then standard restore. It will preserve all IDs that you have. If you mean something different by "migrate", please explain in the question.

Comment: Question updated. Thx all.

Comment: @Henry If a field is an autoincrement integer primary key it doesn't mean you cannot insert arbitrary integer value into that field. I see no problem moving data into another empty database without reassigning anything.

Comment: @FractalizeR thx, but wouldn't that render the identity columns with a lot of gap?  I guess it doesn't matter much as long as they are unique.

Comment: If it is a one-way sync of data, then simply use [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT  table ON | OFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188059.aspx) during the sync and preserve all values of PK and FK. In this case you don't need to reassign anything. So, I don't see any technical problems here. If you need to do something different, please clarify in the question. If you don't want or can't use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`, then clarify in the question why. Gaps between int IDs when you sync the data only partially? GUIDs have random gaps between them as well, so I don't see it as an argument.

Comment: You might want to do a little bit of research on MDM, your issue sounds somewhat common at a high level.  If the two systems contain two different sets of ID for customer you might want to consider looking at a registry of sorts. think of a table with a single identifier for the customer and then references to the ID in other source systems.

Comment: @BradD master data management (MDM)?  Great, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GUIDs as primary keys are awesome, GUIDs as clustered index keys are not so awesome.  While the PK does default to be clustered, it doesn't necessarily have to be.  If there is another column on the table that would make sense to be clustered, you might consider converting over to non-clustered GUID primary keys and clustering on some other field.

If the PKs on your table are used frequently for filtering and joining, it probably still makes sense for them to be clustered even if they are GUIDs.  Using newsequentialid() will get around most of the problems that are caused by GUID clustered index keys - namely logical index fragmentation, page splits and low page density.  You still have the issue that GUIDs are a large data type and therefore all your indexes (both clustered and non-clustered since they also contain the clustered index key) will be somewhat larger, but I don't think that's necessarily a deal breaker.

The only other solution I can think of other than converting to GUIDs would be to specify identity ranges on each of your databases and add constraints to ensure that there is no overlap in ranges between them.  This of course wouldn't work for existing data, but would prevent the problem from happening in the future as new data being inserted should be unique across your farm.

As with anything in SQL Server, there are very few "always" or "never" rules, GUIDs as primary keys and/or clustered index keys is one of those "it depends" rules, I think in this case the GUID PK might be the right solution.

Comment: Combine this with a discussion of `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`, and most everything is covered.

Comment: Thanks @PamLahoud, what do you think about "Keys That Include a Node Identifier" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011.aspx?  I am evaluating this approach, would 2 int compound keys beat GUIDs?

Comment: As with any question in SQL Server, the right answer is "it depends" :)  I think the 2 int compound key is also a good solution.  2 ints are smaller than 1 GUID so you have that going for you, but I think the development effort of moving to a two-column solution might be greater than changing the datatype of a single column.  From a database perspective, I feel like the only advantage of the 2 column solution is the data size, everything else about the GUID can be mitigated by newsequentialid() unless you ever query for ranges of IDs.

Comment: With that in mind, I think you need to look at your application code to determine which is best.  Will your queries need to take this new site ID into consideration?  Will it need to be added to your WHERE clauses or do you have local code that can effectively ignore it?  What will this do to your indexing strategy?  Those are just some of the things I would consider.

Comment: Shame this isn't two answers as I'd down vote GUID keys and up vote identity ranges. I did this once with a database that was replicated between 120 or so SQL Server Express databases and one enterprise master for a table with 400,000,000 rows. Identity ranges worked reasonably well, just make sure the ranges aren't going to fill up! Consider using bigints to help.

Comment: @PamLahoud well, you can set guid column to be row_id  and then it literally won't occupy any extra space.